# Forcing route to interface, no matter what

Tags: ip-routing

I've got 2 interfaces on my server (**eno1** & **eno2**).
Whenever any process try to reach an IP (lets say 183.182.99.1), I want the traffic to use the **eno2** link.

Here is my current routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 metric 90 
default via 172.22.1.1 dev eno1 metric 100 
183.182.99.1 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 metric 80
```

The problem here is whenever **eno2** is down, then kernel try to reach this IP using **eno1**.
Instead, I want it to fail as if it were offline.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just "insert" a *blackhole* route "between" your two routes. By insert between, I mean use a higher metric than *eno2*'s metric but lower metric than *eno1*'s metric. Of course not having a default route on *eno1* at all would also solve it.

```
# ip route add blackhole default metric 95
```

You can replace `blackhole` (drop) with `prohibit` or `unreachable` to get various ICMP messages instead of nothing (when routing. Local processes immediately get an error even with `blackhole`). `throw` could be used too, but its purpose is different and usually intended for additional ip rules.

If your goal is to protect *only* 183.182.99.1 from using *eno1*, then apply this *only* to this IP, for example, this instead of above (metric doesn't matter much as long as it's above 80, since as usual a shorter netmask (/32) always wins over a larger netmask (/0)):

```
# ip route add blackhole 183.182.99.1 metric 9999
```

Comment: Thanks, the goal was indeed to protect only this IP from being accessed by eno1 while I still needed to have eno1 acting as a secondary gateway in case eno2 was down. Didn't know about blackhole.